# Caching Resources Loaded by Java Applet

Tags: java, caching, applet

How can I control what does and doesn't get cached *by* an applet? Additionally, any insights into how caching works within an applet would be most appreciated.

I'm making a simple request in an applet to try and test if resources loaded at runtime are cached anywhere.

Here's the code that makes the request. I call this several times in a row, all within the same applet lifecycle:

```
URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", 8343, "/spring-social-test/testSession.html");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
            connection.connect();
```

But here's what is output in the Java applet plugin console:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8343/spring-social-test/index.html, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost:8343/spring-social-test/index.html with proxy=DIRECT
```

**Update**

Just to be clear - I need to know under what circumstances things (images) will get cached, as I'm working on a browser-based game prototype wherein my main cost will be bandwidth. I need to know exactly how much bandwidth I'll be using in order to explore business models.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, applet resources were cached eagerly (before anything else happened).  The only way around that was to leave some of the Jars out of the `archive` attribute and (in a trusted applet) establish an `URLClassLoader` to load other resources as needed.

But things change.  Deploy the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and you can have complete control over download behavior on a Jar by Jar basis.

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including **lazy downloads** and **programmatic control of updates),** partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..
>
> ..
>
> JWS was first offered as a separate download on 14 March 2001 over two years after the release of Java 1.2, and could launch both applications and **applets as free floating entities.** The functionality became co-bundled with J2SE 1.4.2. Since 1.6.0_10 (the Next Generation Java Plug-In), JWS can also be used to configure **applets that remain embedded in a web page.**

See an example applet deployed by JWS in this small [Animated GIF maker](http://pscode.org/gifanim/applet.html). That applet is deployed using JWS in order to use the JNLP API services that come with it, which allow a sand-boxed applet to access the local file-system.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm working on a browser-based game, so I'm not sure how applicable JWS would be. Will all browsers that support applets also support JWS applications?

Comment: Was there some part of *"The functionality became co-bundled with J2SE 1.4.2"* that you do not understand?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the answer and the clarification, but there's no need to be sarcastic. I'm just trying to get to grips with an area of Java I know little about, and its easy to miss details when inundated with a deluge of new information.

Comment: *"there's no need to be sarcastic"*  Sure there is.  It helps 'cut through the deluge'.

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing go to  ControlPanel>Programs>JAVA>General>Settings>DeleteFiles

Delete cached application and applet. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the problem I'm trying to solve. I don't want to clear my cache, I want to know under what circumstances resources requested at runtime will be cached.